# jQuery ui prevent children to be handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd tried to make an object to be draggable, and just want it's handle to be
it's padding area, not to be all of it's children, is there any way to do this?

some question refer to use

```
$('#my-object').draggable({cancel: ".class1, .class2"});
```

but why do I need to add a specific child while there is a new?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make just part of the element act as the handle, but you can at least add a child element that covers all of the draggable element except its padding, and then use the `cancel` option as you mention in your question.

Html:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <div class="client-area">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.draggable {
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
}
.client-area {
    cursor: default;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    cancel: '.client-area',
    cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydagaey1/)